# Loading iptables rules from /etc/init.d/

Tags: ubuntu, iptables

I decided to load my iptables rules from /etc/init.d/ on my Ubuntu 15 server.

Is this good practice?

Here is the script I have:

```
#!/bin/sh

iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules
exit 0
```

By the way it works. I just want to make sure this way of loading my iptables rules won't break anything or cause security issues.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? There is already an `iptables-persistent` package with the necessary scripts.

Comment: Actually there is no "best practice" in configuration of iptables. Everyone do it in some strange way and it pretty differs between distros.

Comment: As @MichaelHampton already pointed, use *iptables-persistent* and save your rules in */etc/iptables/rules.v?* - *?* for IP protocol version (4 or 6).